# Saving image in picture box to specific directory

Tags: c#, winforms, aforge

I am trying to save webcam image in directory using AForge.NET.

Here is my Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    FilterInfoCollection webcam;
    VideoCaptureDevice cam;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
        webcam = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
        cam = new VideoCaptureDevice(webcam[0].MonikerString);
        cam.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(cam_NewFrame);
        cam.Start();   
    }

    void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
        pictureBox1.Image.Save("c:\\image\\image1.jpg");
    }
```

But i am getting this exception:

`InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Object is currently in use elsewhere.
If you are using Graphic objects after the GetHdc method, call the RealseHdc method.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2008/01/28/quot-object-is-currently-in-use-elsewhere-quot-error.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is this line:

```
pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;
pictureBox1.Image.Save("c:\\image\\image1.jpg");
```

You are trying to save image that is not yet properly loaded and also you are facing cross-threading.

The solution in this case is to not use multiple threads when drawing.

```
void cam_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    bitmap = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    pictureBox1.Image = bitmap;

         try
         {
             this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
             {
                 //saves image on its thread

                 pictureBox1.Image.Save("c:\\image\\image1.jpg");

             });
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
         }
 }
```